# Swift XCTest - How to test properties of tabItems in a TabView?

Tags: swift, testing, swiftui, xctest

Consider the following struct

```
struct MainView: View {
    // The `Model` the   `User` shall be read from
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            AccountsOverview()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.stack")
                Text("Accounts")
            }
            TransactionOverview()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                Text("Transactions")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to write a XCTest that tests if the second tab item

- has an Image with the systemName list.dash
- has a Text "Transactions"

Appreciate your input!

Comment: Why would you like to test that?

Comment: As part of an automated test for student exercises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing you are trying to test/validate is a `View` and for testing `View` one should use either `SnapshotTests` or `UITests`. In here I would suggest to start with `SnapshotTests` to verify your view component.

Considering following is your view you want to test

```
class Model: ObservableObject {}

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            AccountsOverview()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.stack")
                    Text("Accounts")
                }
            TransactionOverview()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                    Text("Transactions")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct AccountsOverview: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("AccountsOverview")
    }
}

struct TransactionOverview: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TransactionOverview")
    }
}
```

Now there are many frameworks available to achieve snapshot test but you can use [SnapshotTesting](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing) library from PointFree. Refer this article from [Kodeco](https://www.kodeco.com/24426963-snapshot-testing-tutorial-for-swiftui-getting-started) to start with SnapshotTesting.

Following is the snapshot test for you View:

```
import XCTest
import SnapshotTesting
@testable import <your project target>

class MainViewSnapshotTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() throws {
        let view = MainView()
        assertSnapshot(matching: view, as: .image)
    }
}
```

Following is the reference snapshot generated using above snapshot test.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[ViewInspector](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector) is a third-party library for unit-testing SwiftUI. We can find the second tab item with

```swift
let tabItem = try MainView().inspect().tabView().view(TransactionOverview.self, 1).tabItem()
```

This confirms that `MainView` contains a `TabView`. It looks for the second child (that is, index 1) and confirms that it is a `TransactionOverview`. Then it returns an inspectable representation of the `TabItem`.

We can then search within this `TabItem` for a `Text` and get its string:

```swift
let text = try tabItem.find(ViewType.Text.self).string()
```

Finally, we can check that this text matches:

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(text, "Transactions")
```

Checking the image is a little trickier, because there is no way to ask a standard `Image`, "Were you created using a system name? What was it?" On its own, the `Image` is not examinable.

But as the saying goes, we can solve things by introducing an extra layer. Let's define our own wrapper around `Image`. It will be exactly the same, but it will let us examine the system name:

```swift
struct ExaminableImage: View {
    let systemName: String

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: systemName)
    }
}
```

Use this in place of `Image` to make it testable. Now we can write a second test. It starts the same way, finding the second tab item. Since this is duplicate code, let's use the Extract Method refactoring to create a helper:

```swift
private func secondTabItem() throws -> InspectableView<ViewType.ClassifiedView> {
    try MainView().inspect().tabView().view(TransactionOverview.self, 1).tabItem()
}
```

Now our new test looks inside this second tab item for an `ExaminableImage`. We use a `find` as we did with the `Text` test because we don't care where the image is specified inside. Then we convert this inspectable representation back into the actual view using `actualView()`. Now we can query its system name:

```swift
func test_secondTabItem_image() throws {
    let image = try secondTabItem().find(ExaminableImage.self).actualView()

    XCTAssertEqual(image.systemName, "list.dash")
}
```

Why do this instead of a snapshot test? Snapshots are a nice way to confirm the appearance matches a previously approved image. But for snapshot tests to be fast enough for refactoring, they must match pixel-for-pixel. The images won't match if:

- A machine uses a different chip (especially if you're on Apple Silicon but the build system is running Intel)
- A machine uses a different iOS version
- A machine uses a different simulator (even though the snapshot can specify a simulator size, the actual simulator matters)

These differences are usually minor. There is a way to do fuzzy matching with snapshots to ignore small differences. But this makes snapshot tests much slower.

The reason I want tests is to enable refactoring in small, verified steps. To do that, the tests must be as fast as possible. At their fastest doing pixel-for-pixel matching, snapshot tests are an order of magnitude slower than a regular unit test. They usually still usable for refactoring at that speed. But fuzzy matching slows them down by another order of magnitude.

UITests are so slow, they are out of the question. They also don't allow you to substitute fakes to isolate parts of your system for easier testing.

ViewInspector meets my needs: the tests are fast and stable.